# SQL query to find sum of two particular rows

Tags: mysql

This is my table :

```
id      name         age          role
---------------------------------------
1       Rahul            20              1
2       Karan            35              0
3       Vivek            47              0
4       Shubham          40              1
5       Paras            87              1
6       Arjun            18              1
7       Ayush            28              0
```

I want to select only those two rows which are having the sum of their ages equal to 60 like we have
1st and 4th row in above table. What is the SQL query for that??

I have tried this

```sql
select * from form_data where age=(select age from form_data having sum(age)=60);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?  You do realise that this query is going to increase in time taken as a function N-squared where N is the number of rows.

Comment: select * from form_data where age=(select age from form_data having sum(age)=60);

Comment: You should always update the question, I have done that for you.  Now its worthy of a +1

Comment: Actually i am a begginer

Comment: Do you want any combination or only first one which gave you sum(age) = 60?

Comment: I want1st and 4th row to be selected as they have sum equal to 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a use case for a `CROSS JOIN` to get every combination of rows from 2 tables, using the `form_data` table twice:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM form_data a
    CROSS JOIN form_data b
WHERE a.age + b.age = 60
    -- the following condition prevents getting a combination twice
    AND a.id < b.id
```

Comment: @RiteshKumar you're welcome, it's fun to find use cases for `CROSS JOIN`s. Don't forget to upvote useful answers and accept one when it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to treat the same table as a second table and join them

```sql
select fd1.name as name1, fd2.name as name2, fd1.age as age1, fd2.age as age2
from form_data as fd1, form_data as fd2 
where fd1.age+fd2.age = 60
```

This will give the two names and the two ages that match.  However this will also give you Rahul+Shubam and Shubam+Rahul.

One way of getting around that is to use the id

```sql
select fd1.name as name1, fd2.name as name2, fd1.age as age1, fd2.age as age2
from form_data as fd1, form_data as fd2 
where fd1.age+fd2.age = 60 and fd2.id > fd1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using that table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
`id` int,
`name` VARCHAR(10),
`age` INT,
`role` INT
);

INSERT INTO `testing_database`.`users` (`id`,`name`,`age`,`role`)
VALUES
(1,       "Rahul",          20,              1),
(2,       "Karan",          35,              0),
(3,       "Vivek",          47,              0),
(4,       "Subam",          40,              1),
(5,       "Paras",          87,              1),
(6,       "Arjun",          18,              1),
(7,       "Ayush",          28,              0)
```

I've returned the data with thit query:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.name, 
       t1.role, 
       t1.age as t1_age, 
       t2.age as t2_age,
       (t1.age  + t2.age ) as sum_age
FROM testing_database.users as t1
CROSS JOIN testing_database.users as t2
ON t1.id != t2.id
WHERE (t1.age  + t2.age) = 60
```